# Combining two jQuery function into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to combine my two jQuery functions into one. But I don't know how.
What do I need to change to combine these two into one function?

Here is the Code:

```js
$('#keyword').on('keyup', function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log($(this).text());
    $('input[name="q"]').val($(this).val());
    $('g-search').html($(this).val());
});

$(function () {
    $('#title').on('keyup', function (e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        console.log($(this).val());
        var title = $(this).val();
        $('span.title').text(title);
        $('g-search').html(title);
    });
});
```

Comment: post your HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible check this fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxd08v44/)

```
$('#keyword,#title').on('keyup', function (e) {

        console.log(e.keyCode);

        console.log($(this).text());

        $('input[name="q"]').val($(this).val());

        $('g-search').html($(this).val());

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write your logic in a single function by like this in case of different types of events.

```
$(function () {
    $('#keyword').on('keyup', function (e) {
        anotherFunction(this);
    });
    $('#title').on('keyup', function (e) {
            anotherFunction(this);
    });
});

function anotherFunction(val){

}
```

Or you can do like this.

```
$('#keyword,#title').on('keyup', function (e) {


});
```

Comment: thats a good answer but then  i cant write into different span containers.

Answer (score 2):

Add a common class to each element

html:

```
<input class="key common-class" type="text" size="50" maxlength="63" id="keyword"/>

<input class="url1 common-class"  type="text" data-limit="60" size="50" maxlength="74" id="url"/>
```

js:

```
$('.common-class').on('keyup', function (e) {
      //combined code 
      var val = $(this).val();
   if($(e.target).is('#keyword')) {
     $('input[name="q"]').val(val);
   } else {
    $('span.title').text(val);
   }
   $('g-search').html(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add your both `Ids` on same `event`
function like below code.

```
$('#keyword,#title').on('keyup', function (e) {
  //Your code
})
```

Comment: but then i write with both input fields in the same span

Comment: if anything should be separate in function then i would suggest you to use desperate function only. common function will be useful when requirement is some for both function